# Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation when clearing large Table

Tags: vb.net, memory-management, overflow, html-table, underflow

I'm building large (>25,000 rows) `Table`s.

I receive the dreaded `Overflow or underflow` error somewhere above 25,000 rows.

I've tried to reset with psuedo

```
Table = Nothing
Table = New Table
Table.Rows.Clear()
```

Now, the reset line is referenced in the trace for the same error.

How should this problem be handled?

Comment: Have you tried calling the garbage collector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the garbage collector:

```
GC.Collect()
```